# Minimum number of subsets required to satisfy a condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

Consider the set $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, and consider a family of subsets of this set, satisfying the following condition:

$$\forall \ i,j,k \in[n], i\ne j,j\ne k,i\ne k$$there exists a subset $A$ in this family such that $i,j\in A$, and $k \notin A$.

What is the minimum size of such a family? I very strongly feel it's equal to $O(log(n)^2)$, but am not able to prove this. Thanks in advance

Comment: For pairs instead of triples, the minimum size is $O(\log_2 n)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242984/a-distinguishing-family-of-subsets

Comment: Have you considered choosing the family randomly? Since each 3-tuple has probability $1 / 8$ to be shattered by a single $A$, taking $\Theta(\log n)$ subsets should shatter all tuples.

Comment: Optimal values for $n\in[13]$ are $0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10$.

Answer (score 1):

I am turning Shengtong Zheng's commment into an snwer.

Using the probabilistic method, you can prove that $O(\log n)$ sets suffice.

Suppose we choose $m$ sets from $2^{[n]}$, uniformly at random. There are $O(n^3)$ ordered triples $(i,j,k)\in [n]^3$, and for each triple, the probability that there does not exist a chosen set which contains $i$ and $j$, but not $k$, is $(7/8)^m$. The expected number of "bad" triples is
$$
n^3(7/8)^m
$$
If you choose $m$ to be greater than $\log_{7/8}(n^{-3})\in O(\log n)$, then the expected number of bad triples is less than $1$, so  there must a particular random choice with zero bad triples.

I do not know a constructive way to prove this result.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I'd like to use Thanksgiving as an excuse, but I was just careless. Fixed now.